# WCF and updating svcutil proxy

Tags: web-services, wcf, proxy, svcutil.exe

I have a WCF service that I am running on a local server. This is something of a development server that we can test on. My service runs fine. I have generated a .cs file using svcutil.exe. We will eventually move this service to a customer's production server. My question is as follows: What is the proper way to handle the svcutil proxy class in this situation. We are wanting to deploy our updated application to use the WCF service at the same time we are deploying our WCF service onto the production server. Is there any way to do that or will I have to have the service running and generate a new proxy using that service? All help appreciated.

Comment: If the service in production is the same as the service in your dev environment, then you shouldn't need to change the proxy.  You'll have to update the URL to the service, but that should be done via the config file so you can change it without changing and recompiling the code.

Comment: Ah, ok. So all I would need to do is change the endpoint address. Correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.